# How to attach a trigged event and its information to a PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, events, scripting, powershell-3.0, event-viewer

I currently have been able to create a task on the Windows Server 2012 R2 I have, and also have created a script that gets executed when a particular event has occurred. However, there are a couple of events and I need the script to specify which event has occurred. It is not possible for me to specify a separate event for each task that occurs. Is there a way to pass the event information into the script from the task creation or through another method, and if so, how?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: If anyone can help with this, i would greatly appreciate it.